# Why mono and dioxides of germanium,tin and lead are amphoteric

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, physical-chemistry, reactivity, oxides, lead

I get that group 14 elements show +4 and +2 oxidation states so they can form both ionic and covalent compounds and so they are amphoteric but monoxide means that these elements have to show +2 oxidation state in these oxides and dioxide means that the oxidation state of these elements will be +4.

Monoxides of ge,sn and pb should be ionic because of fajan's rule and dioxides should be covalent then why are they amphoteric? I know that it is because they react with both alkali and acids but what is the reason for such behaviour?

Comment: Related: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40651/what-is-an-acidic-oxide

Answer (score 1):

Consider that elements in Group 1 are far **less** [electronegative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electronegativity) than than those amphoteric elements, and in Group 17, they're far **more** electronegative.

In solution , $\ce{Na+}$ readily donates an electron to tin, for example, form [sodium stannate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sodium_stannate), $\ce{Na2(Sn(OH)6)}$.

On the other side, $\ce{Cl-}$ readily attracts an electron to form [tin(II) chloride](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tin(II)_chloride).